# Can you eat a druid?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, druid, wild-shape, food-and-drink

First context:
In my recent game our party was travelling through some barren wasteland and we were short on food, fortunately we have druid in a party so we think of using wildshape ability to create food. Our druid transformed himself in a swine and we wanted to gather ham from him, that's not killing because as wildshape description states:
"You automatically revert if you fall unconscious, drop to 0 hit points, or die(source: https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#WildShape-167)"

Killing the pig means to bring it's hp to 0 points so druid will reverse to his normal form.

That started a pretty heated disscusion about what happen with meat when druid return to his normal form? Is it disappear or not?
One argument was that word "transform" in a ability description means transmutation so the wildshape is physical form and meat(or hair or anything which can be gather from an animal) exists, physically so there is no reason to it disapear after reversing.
The counter-argument was prestidigation cantrip. This is a transmutation cantrip where what you create disappear as stated in description:
"You create a nonmagical trinket or an illusory image that can fit in your hand and that lasts until the end of your next turn" (source: https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/prestidigitation)
The gm argument was this can make druid class broken. Imagine using druid to generate fur or leather and making armor from it, and then selling it(or using it). Or generate food and drink(cow's milk) on the desert. Or creating some spell components(like bat guano for fireball(https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fireball)) That can be pretty op sometimes.

Now the question:

Are there any official rules which tell what happen with resources gathered from a wildshape animal or is it up to gm?

We are playing DnD 5e, but if such a rule existed in previous verions we consider it official.

Comment: I’ve closed this as a duplicate since it has been asked before.

Comment: Ok, I couldn't find it :)

Comment: @Maxxer If you have a willing druid helping out, why would they choose to be chopped up as a wildshaped pig rather than just expend a 1st level spell slot to cast goodberry?

Comment: @Jon
I don't remember a situation exactly but our druid was out of slots and we wanted to make many food rations from this meat(as goodberry "lasts" only 24 hours). There is also a possibility that we were too deep in our discussion and didn't think of that(that was first idea we thouht of, for some reason) :)